# Evaluating $\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta } }{\sin3\theta } } $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta  }  }{\sin3\theta  }  } $$

My impression:

I don't see how I can change the variables in any way to get it in the form where I can simplify it to 1. I also looked up similar problems and they mention L'Hopital's rule to solve this, which I haven't learned yet. Do not give a straight answer. I already have that available to me.

Comment: Hint: Break it up into the product of two limits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta  }  }{ sin3\theta  }  } = \lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta  }  }{ sin3\theta  } \cdot \frac{\theta}{\theta}} =  \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\sin(7\theta)}{\theta} } \cdot {\frac{\theta}{sin(3\theta)} }$$

And then do each limit independently.

Comment: I see how to go from here... but wouldn't it become $\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta  }  }{ 1 }  } \cdot \lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ sin3\theta  }  } $

I don't get where you got the $\theta$

Comment: Sorry, I'll make an edit

Comment: Basically all I did was multiply the top and bottom by $\theta$

Comment: Sorry, still confused... $\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin { 7\theta  }  }{ 1 }  } \cdot \frac { \theta  }{ \theta  } =\lim _{ \theta \rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \theta \sin { 7\theta  }  }{ \theta  }  } $ no? Where did the $\theta$ in the numerator disappear to?

Comment: It went to the otehr limit

Comment: Look at it now, maybe it is more clear

Comment: I'm sorry. I must be having some kind of brain malfunction. I still cannot see it..

Comment: Which part are you having trouble seeing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20374/discussion-between-cherry-developer-and-askask).

Answer (score 4):

If you're allowed to use Taylor series, note that $\sin(k\theta) \approx k\theta$ when $\theta$ is near zero:

Solution using this technique, now that I see you probably have solved this:

> $$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin(7\theta)}{\sin(3\theta)} = \lim_{\theta\to0}\frac{7\theta}{3\theta} = \frac{7}{3}$$